# How to build PCRE 8.44 without linking to gcc

Tags: linux, httpd, pcre

I'm building a custom version of Apache HTTPD with a whole slew of extra modules. As part of this, I'm linking against PCRE 8.44, which is working fine. However, `lib/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.2` has a dependency showing for libgcc_s.so.1 via `/usr/bin/env -i ldd`.

I do not want to have gcc installed on production servers, especially not extranet production servers. I cannot seem to find any combination of flags that will build a PCRE that does not link to libgcc. I'm fairly certain that disabling C++ support would do it, but that's hardly optimal and I haven't actually tried it.

Is there a way to build PCRE such that it doesn't link to gcc?

Current settings are:

```
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,${PREFIX}/lib -Wl,-rpath,${PREFIX}/lib64 -L${PREFIX}/lib -L${PREFIX}/lib64
CFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,${PREFIX}/lib -Wl,-rpath,${PREFIX}/lib64 -I${PREFIX}/include
CPPFLAGS=${CFLAGS}

export LDFLAGS CFLAGS CPPFLAGS PREFIX

./configure \
  --prefix="${PREFIX}" \
  --enable-pcre16 \
  --enable-pcre32 \
  --enable-jit \
  --enable-utf \
&& make \
&& make install
```

(If folks have suggestions for better configuration options I'm listening.)

UPDATE:
It appears that turning off shared libraries for pcre works. Testing is required to ensure that everything worked correctly, but I think I've got a statically linked pcre baked in where needed, which is acceptable to me. If anyone has ideas on how to build shared libraries *without* linking to gcc I would love to hear it, though.

UPDATE 2:
Looks like mod_security does *not* want to build using httpd's built-in pcre, so I'm back to stuck.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Solved for real. Turns out nothing in `httpd` nor the extras I'm adding to it actually require `libpcrecpp` so I was able to just add `--disable-cpp` and skip building it entirely. If I ever need to build something that requires C++ support I'll need to actually figure this out, but for now I'm just not building the library in question and all is well.